# Korg device not detected MIDI on W10

Tags: powershell, windows-10, midi

Does anyone have any idea why my Korg Minilogue XD is not detected (on USB) by the Windows 10 MIDI API?

I'm using Pete Brown's Powershell library at https://github.com/Psychlist1972/Windows-10-PowerShell-MIDI.

I've checked and installed the latest Korg driver from their website.

Running list-midi-example.ps1 all I get (as an output) is the Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth.

If I connect an M-Audio dumb controller keyboard this is detected fine. The Korg Librarian also works okay, so no basic comms issue to the Korg.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Follow instructions on you link.

Comment: Can you please check the list of input devices with my [ReceiveMidiData](https://artprodsu6weu.artifacts.visualstudio.com/Ada86e53e-02d0-42a7-ad86-d86986ae81da/d286d31e-d5f6-443f-b126-d81074c91872/_apis/artifact/cGlwZWxpbmVhcnRpZmFjdDovL01lbGFuY2hhbGwvcHJvamVjdElkL2QyODZkMzFlLWQ1ZjYtNDQzZi1iMTI2LWQ4MTA3NGM5MTg3Mi9idWlsZElkLzI1MzA3L2FydGlmYWN0TmFtZS9VdGlsaXR5LXdpbi14NjQ1/content?format=file&subPath=%2FMelanchall.ReceiveMidiData.6.1.4-win-x64.zip) utility? Is your device detected?

Comment: @Maxim - yes, your utility detects it. (0: minilogue xd 1 MIDI IN
1: minilogue xd 1 KBD/KNOB).

Comment: The device also appears in Devices and Printers (Windows 'knows' that it is there), so I guess that points to an issue in Pete Brown's Powershell library.

Comment: Sounds like I was dissing Pete's library there, not my intention at all.  If I uninstall the Korg driver the library works fine with the Minilogue XD using the default Windows drivers.